No Items in the website after setting firebase
So I was running a GitHub repo of an auction website.
https://github.com/hmellor/auction-website?tab=readme-ov-file
I've followed all the instructions. At first, like when I ran the dev server at first, the items could be seen, but after setting up firebase, I can't see any items. I followed the instructions in the repo and created a user database. I don't know what seems to be the issue...
I tried debugging by checking the codes but I'm not able to fix it.

I have posted an answer, if this answer has helped you, you can mark this answer as accepted for future viewers that may come and have the same issue.

I have made a few suggestions that I would recommend doing and see if any of these solve your issue:

Make sure that the Firebase configuration in your project matches the one in your Firebase console. This includes the Firebase project ID, API key, and other details.

Firebase has security rules that determine who has read and write access to your database. Make sure that your rules allow access to the items you’re trying to display.

Use console.log() or similar debugging tools to check if the data is being fetched correctly from Firebase. This can help you identify if the issue is with displaying the data or fetching it.

Sometimes, the issue might be due to changes in Firebase or the libraries you’re using. Check the Firebase documentation and the GitHub repo for any updates or reported issues.


